# Is there armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a system images for older api levels?

Tags: android, arm, android-virtual-device, arm64

I need armeabi-v7a system images for the following API levels: 16, 17, 18, 19, 26, 27, 28, 29. And arm64-v8a system images for API levels 21-29.

In Android SDK package API levels 16-19 for armeabi-v7a are currently available, but they MB don't work properly. And there are no system images for arm64-v8a. I couldn't find any old archives anywhere. I'm also ready to build them myself thought but didn't find any proper instruction on how to do that. It will be really helpful if you can provide a link to that instruction or MB you know where I can find those images.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks